# Multiple instances on a single machine on Couchbase 2.2 community

Tags: couchbase

We are trying to setup multiple instances on a single machine for our development environment using Couchbase 2.2 community edition. We see that there is documentation for such a set up using enterprise 2.5 edition here http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#installing-multiple-instances-on-a-machine. We tried to see the difference between both the versions and there doesn't seem to be a change in the static_config files nor the coucbase-server bin script. So is it safe to assume that the instructions for 2.5 enterprise edition would still work on 2.2 community edition or is there a better way to set up such an environment?

Answer (score 0):

Personally when I want to run more than one node locally I spin up virtual machines and have a node installed on each one.

Two really nice blog posts that will guide you through this are:

Create a Couchbase cluster with Ansible:

http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/create-couchbase-cluster-in-one-command.html

or

A couchbase cluster with Vagrant and Puppet:

http://nitschinger.at/A-Couchbase-Cluster-in-Minutes-with-Vagrant-and-Puppet

Comment: Our development environments are already on a VM that is provisioned by Ansible so, having to manage two VMs will highly impediment the speed of our development. Hence the requirement of running 2 instances on the same machine.

Comment: Ok well then your only way forward is to try the process you listed in your question, try it and then come back with any problems!