# Couchbase Multiple Instances

Tags: couchbase

I found questions on how to run many couchbase instances in one PC.([here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864347/multiple-instances-on-a-single-machine-on-couchbase-2-2-community))
Most of other solutions found out there was to run couchbase in a virtual machine. but if another couchbase runs inside virtual box, we may not able to get exact performance and expected output.

Therefore, I m trying to run more instances with different ports. Couchbase document explain [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#installing-multiple-instances-on-a-machine) how to do so. I made changes in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config` files. But the rest of the document is not clear for me.

Specially followings(extracted in Couchbase documentation).

> Change the two occurrences short_name in the
>   /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server file. For example, use the sed
>   utility. sed -i ’s/ns_1/ns_inst1/g' bin/couchbase-server Start the
>   Couchbase instance. Repeat the steps to install other instances.

What this means the two occurances ?
use the sed
"utility. sed -i ’s/ns_1/ns_inst1/g' bin/couchbase-server" means ?

How to install another Couchbase server ? Normally installation is with `dpkg` and it may install the same thing over again.

Please any one let me explain more step by step please on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Well as it seems you are trying to install at least two instance of Couchbase on same host which is not performant and also not good idea about deployment strategy.

I suggest you to use [Couchbase Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchbase/) and use [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) to deploy multiple instance of Couchbase on same device or multiple devices.

I have written an article about Couchbase consideration on deployment clustering and performance which I recommend to read before deployment.
https://medium.com/@sunnystatue/big-scale-consideration-and-architecture-using-couchbase-docker-nginx-node-js-and-jenkins-938fefc07909

You need to change your approach to deployment and scaling, because Couchbase is a good Hardware consumer with CPUs and RAMs so you need at least two linux instance with minimum hardware requirement then start clustering because this is the way folks at Couchbase recommend to use their product.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the beginnig was confussing to me too, Just search for the two occurrences of that name(ns_1) in that file(one of them is something like ns_1@172..... ) If you use nano you can use ctrl+w to find them, then replace them with your new instance name, that worked for me.

BR.